# Call Codeignier 4 model function In Controller

Tags: model, codeigniter-4

I cant call get_user_by_id() Using Codeigniter 4. Whick is the quick fixes for this?

````
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\UserModel;
class Home extends BaseController
{
    protected $base;

    public function index()
    {

        $this->base = new UserModel(); // Create an instance
        $this->base->get_user_by_id();
        return view('welcome_message');
    }
}```
````

Answer (score -1):

In Codeigniter 4 `get_user_by_id()` turns into `getUserById`.
try using this:

```
$this->base = new UserModel(); // Create an instance
$this->base->getUserById();
return view('welcome_message');
```